# Как убрать расстояние между блоками в QGridLayout при fixed/maximum/size виджетов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlayout, qgridlayout

Если попытаться ограничить размер виджета, то при `spacing=0` исчезает только горизонтальное пространство.

Возможно ли убрать и вертикальное используя `QGridLayout`?

Догадываюсь, что можно этого избежать используя `QVBoxLayout` / `QHBoxLayout`. 
Я не нашел в примеров именно с `QGridLayout`:

```
...

def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    gridbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(spacing = 0)

    box1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    box2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    boxes = [box1, box2]
    for box in boxes:
        box.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        box.setFixedSize(200, 100)

    gridbox.addWidget(box1, 0, 0)
    gridbox.addWidget(box2, 0, 1)

    widget =  QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    mainbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    mainbox.addLayout(gridbox)
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    self.setMinimumSize(500, 500)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Установить расстояние между элементами в данном лейауте можно так:

```py
grid = QGridLayout() #QGridLayout(spacing = 0) тоже работает

# Установка вертикального и горисонтального расстояния между виджетами 
grid.setSpacing(0)

# Установка горизонтального расстояния между виджетами 
grid.setHorizontalSpacing(0)

# Установка вертикального расстояния между виджетами 
grid.setVerticalSpacing(0)
```

**Пример кода:**

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        gridbox = QGridLayout(spacing = 0)

        box1 = QWidget(self)
        box2 = QWidget(self)
        box3 = QWidget(self)
        box4 = QWidget(self)
        box1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        box2.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
        box3.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        box4.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")

        gridbox.addWidget(box1, 0, 0)
        gridbox.addWidget(box2, 0, 1)
        gridbox.addWidget(box3, 1, 0)
        gridbox.addWidget(box4, 1, 1)

        panel =  QWidget(self)
        panel.setLayout(gridbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(panel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Легче зафиксировать/контролировать размер виджета-панели, на которой все это расположено (в примере это `panel`), чем просто задавать ограничения в размерах на внутренние виджеты и пытаться контролировать расстояние между ними. Мне кажется, что можно все это комбинировать.

При отсутствии пространства между внутренними виджетами размер виджета-панели является суммой сторон внутренних.

Например:

```
box1.setFixedSize(200, 100)
box2.setFixedSize(200, 100)
```

тогда размеры панели:

```
panel.setFixedSize(QSize(400,200))
```

Comment: это ничего не меняет

Comment: @whyeaye добавил пример кода

Answer (score 0):

> QGridLayout::`setColumnStretch`(int column, int stretch)
>
> Устанавливает коэффициент растяжения (stretch)  для столбца (column). Первый столбец - номер **0**.
>
> Коэффициент растяжения относительно других столбцов в этой сетке. Столбцы с более высоким коэффициентом растяжения занимают больше доступного пространства.
>
> Коэффициент растяжения по умолчанию равен **0**.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget =  QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
#        self.setMinimumSize(500, 500)
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(styleSheet="background-color: red;")
        self.box1.setFixedSize(200, 100)
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(styleSheet="background-color: green;")
        self.box2.setFixedSize(200, 100)

        gridbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget, spacing=0)
        gridbox.addWidget(self.box1, 1, 1)
        gridbox.addWidget(self.box2, 1, 2)   
        gridbox.setColumnStretch(0, 1) 
        gridbox.setColumnStretch(3, 1)        
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = MyWindow()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @whyeaye что не так?